# What is the multiplicity of errors that can be detected using the following checking matrix and why?

Tags: matrices

I want to pre-face by saying this *is* a homework question, however, I've done some research and have no idea how to do them.

The question is: what are the multiplicity of errors that can be detected using the following checking matrix and why?

[image]

[image]

I do know what multiplicity of errors are - it just means how many errors I can detect or correct. I've also done a lot of homework problems that deal with the multiplicity of errors, but not one with a check matrix. Checking Google also didn't return many results as well.